# Adding Variable to URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to set up an apache config for a virtual server with a domain example.com. When this domain is called, as long as the user is surfing on this domain, a variable with a static value should be added via mod_rewrite.

https://example.com should be https://example.com?space=5555

https://example.com/home.php should be https://example.com/home.php?space=5555

https://example.com/home.php?systemid=1 sould be https://example.com/home.php?systemid=1&space=5555

Answer (score 0):

solved it with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "!space"
RewriteRule "^/(.*)$" "/$1?space=5555$1%{QUERY_STRING}" [L,R]
```